# Google Custom Search v2 fails to load on Ajax

Tags: ajax, search, google-custom-search

I'm changing my website to ajax + pushstate technology and I'm getting into some problems.

I already manage to fix twitter, facebook and google+ buttons, but I can't find the function to reload the google custom search box.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
<script>
(function() {
var cx = 'google_search_id';
var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = false;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com.br/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
```